# React native router flux authentication flow for tabs as in show accounts tab in case of unauthorize and show profile tab in case of authorize

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

In my app, the authentication is not the first screen to be shown. The home page contains a list of item that a user can browse through and see the details of an individual item. In order, to subscribe to that item, I need to redirect the user to the accounts tab. In case user is logged in, I want to show the profile tab otherwise the login page which has is part of an auth stack of pages.

So how can I do that using react-native-router-flux, I have tried the following approach as per my understanding and it isn't working. I am new to react-native and struggling with this flow.

If there is another library which can help me to achieve this desired behavior, I would love to try it out.

Routing.tsx

```
<Router>
        <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
            <Tabs key="tabbar" swipeEnabled tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar} showLabel={false} lazy>
                <Scene key="homeTab" title="Home" iconName="ios-home" icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar>
                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home Page" initial />
                    <Scene key="details" component={ContentDetail} />
                </Scene>

                <Scene key="account" component={Splash} hideNavBar title="Profile" iconName="ios-person" icon={TabIcon}>
                    <Scene key="profileTab" title="Profile" iconName="ios-person" icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar>
                        <Scene key="profile" component={Profile} initial />
                    </Scene>
                    <Scene key="authTab" title="Account" iconName="ios-person" icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar>
                        <Scene key="login" component={Login} initial />
                        <Scene key="signup" component={Signup} />
                        <Scene key="verifyTac" component={VerifyTac} />
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="settingTab" title="Settings" iconName="ios-settings" icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar>
                    <Scene key="accInfo" component={AccountInfo} title="Account Info Page" initial />
                </Scene>
            </Tabs>
            <Scene
                key="search"
                component={Search}
                modal
                hideNavBar
            />
        </Scene>
    </Router>
```

Splash.tsx

```
class Splash extends React.Component<Props, {}> {

constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.user && this.props.user.accessToken) Actions.replace('profileTab');
    else Actions.replace('authTab');
}

render() {
    console.log(' Splash props: ', this.props);
    return <View></View>
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        user: state.authReducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Splash);
```